# Cannot connect to the OpenSSL server with OPENSSL_NO_HEARTBEATS enabled

Tags: openssl, heartbeat, heartbleed-bug

I have a server running OpenSSL v 0.9.8 and a client based on OpenSSL 1.0.1e. When the client OpenSSL library compiled with -DOPENSSL_NO_HEARTBEATS it cannot connect to server. The only thing I see is a error page. 
Please suggest something. What are the ways to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL version 1.0.1g resolves heartbleed vulnerability. The 1.0.0 and 0.9.8 branches are not vulnerable.So upgrade/backpatch the client accordingly.